# Efficiently Getting Second Element of std::*_heap

Tags: c++, stl

After rigorous profiling, I have determined that the most expensive operations in my program are heap operations on a fairly small (usually <5, almost always <20) heap.

One such operation is getting the second element (i.e., the one below the head).  The current way I get the second element is fairly naïve:

1. Remove the first element
2. Check the head
3. Push the element back

I'm assuming that heaps created with e.g. std::make_heap do not need to be laid out in any particular way (e.g. the left side comes first).  This complicates just taking e.g. the second element of the backing store.

A linear search would be pretty fast in this case, but again, I'm trying to squeeze all the performance out of this as possible.

So, question: **Is there an implementation-independent method to query the second element of heaps created using std::*_heap that is more efficient than just removing the first element and seeing what's on top?**

Comment: *"I'm assuming that heaps created with e.g. std::make_heap do not need to be laid out in any particular way"* `make_heap` guarantees that the first element (lhs) is the largest element (wrt the predicate).

Comment: @dyp: yes, but _besides_ that?

Comment: Besides that, no guarantees. -- If [b, e) is your heap, you could try operating on [next(b), e), for example with a linear search, or another `make_heap`. Or maybe another data structure / algorithm, like a full sort, or `nth_element`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better or worse, `make_heap` isn't defined quite strictly enough to guarantee exactly what sort of heap it creates.

You may want to implement your own binary heap, which will let you implement this very quickly (constant complexity). On a normal binary heap (which is what `make_heap` *probably* creates, but there's no guarantee of it) the child nodes of some node N are always at 2N and 2N+1. There's no guarantee *which* of those two will be the next item in the heap, so you have to check both.

The same *basic* idea will apply to other kinds of heaps, but the exact location may vary (and thus the advice that you may want to implement your own, much as I hate to give that particular advice).

Comment: In this case, I would suggest to use the standard implementation, and a test case which verifies the assumed constraint. If the impl. violates this assumption, you can still fix it or roll your own.

Comment: @erenon: If you want your code to be portable, you're going to have to roll your own anyway. If you're writing the code anyway, testing the standard implementation just adds more complexity.